i can't visualize my data from my database in my map
i want to get my data from my database postgresql (cloud) so using a function "get_data" to import my data from my database into my map (web application). the problem is i have to determine each and every fields of properties (e.g the columns names and their types) for it to actually work. and when i use a developed version of my function that extract all columns names of my table and add them to features on it's own, it doesn't work no data is shown in my map. and when i use inspect and go to console i get this error :
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [Column('geom', Geometry(srid=4326, spatial_index=False, from_text='ST_GeomFromEWKT', name='geometry', _spatial_index_reflected=True), table=<test1>), Column('properties', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), table=<test1>)]. Did you mean to say select(Column('geom', Geometry(srid=4326, spatial_index=False, from_text='ST_GeomFromEWKT', name='geometry', _spatial_index_reflected=True), table=<test1>), Column('properties', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), table=<test1>))?

of course all this when i use the developed version of my function 'get_data'.
what can i do for it to work?
oh and i use flask as framework for my web application
here's my case with scripts :
- this is the code function that works :




`@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    # Récupérer les données de la table "grp"
    query = grp_table.select()
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(query)
        rows = result.fetchall()

    # Convertir les données géométriques non vides en GeoJSON
    features = []
    for row in rows:
        if row.geom is not None and row.geom != "":
            try:
                geometry = loads(bytes.fromhex(row.geom.data.hex()))
                geojson_geom = mapping(geometry)
                feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "gid": row.gid,
                    "code_const": row.code_const,
                    "quartier": row.quartier,
                    "adresse": row.adresse,
                    "nom": row.nom,
                    "cin": row.cin,
                    "nb_2007": row.nb_2007,
                    "nb_2020": row.nb_2020,
                    "obs": row.obs,
                    "adhésion": row.adhesion
                },
                "geometry": geojson_geom
            }
                features.append(feature)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Erreur lors de la conversion de la géométrie : {e}")

    # Créer un objet GeoJSON à partir des features
    geojson_data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}
    return jsonify(geojson_data)`




- and this what i use but it doesn't work :




`@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    # Récupérer les données de la table "grp"
    query = select([grp_table])
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(query)
        rows = result.fetchall()

    # Créer une liste de features GeoJSON
    features = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            # Convertir la géométrie en format Shapely
            geometry = loads(row.geom.data)
            # Convertir la géométrie Shapely en GeoJSON
            geojson_geom = mapping(geometry)
            
            # Créer les propriétés de l'entité à partir des colonnes de la table
            feature_properties = {}
            for column in row.keys():
                if column != 'geom':
                    feature_properties[column] = getattr(row, column)
            
            # Créer l'entité (feature)
            feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": feature_properties,
                "geometry": geojson_geom
            }
            features.append(feature)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors de la conversion : {e}")

    # Créer un objet GeoJSON à partir des features
    geojson_data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}
    return jsonify(geojson_data)`

where's the problem and how can i solve it?

